# Bootstrap modal popups from bottom of the screen with full width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make bootstrap modal pop ups from bottom of the screen like picture bellow. Is there anyway with bootstrap modal or is there any plugin that does this? And I want to cover the whole width.
My css is as follow

```
#myModal3 {
  bottom:50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 0%;
}
#myModal3 .modal-dialog  {
  width:100%;
}
```

Which doesn't work the way it should be.
 [image]

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```css
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController)
    {
        filteredTableData.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
        
        let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text)
        let array = (tableData as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
        filteredTableData = array as! [String]
        
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="slide-bottom-popup" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="false">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <p>I'm a pop sliding from the bottom that's suppose to stick</p>
        <a href="" class="btn-primary btn-plain btn popup-button">CTA</a>
    </div><!-- /.modal-body -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Also read it here: [Make twitter Bootstrap popup modal slide and stick to bottom of page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26598291/make-twitter-bootstrap-popup-modal-slide-and-stick-to-bottom-of-page)

Comment: Thank you. But how can I create a shadow on the background content? Like what bootstrap modal does?