# jQuery/bootstrap way to create a promotion slideup on a website page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How to create a promotion slideup like the one below using Bootstap/jQuery built-it capabilities:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can check this [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/jme11/51wro3fc/)

Original post here :- [Make twitter Bootstrap popup modal slide and stick to bottom of page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26598291/make-twitter-bootstrap-popup-modal-slide-and-stick-to-bottom-of-page)

Comment: Please edit the externally hosted code into the post; doing so will make sure it remains useful even if the link breaks. My script [is not allowed to do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344512/4751173) because of potential licensing problems.