# how to show popup on the bottom of webpage above footer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have `popup` which display after 10 seconds when page load.But i want that it display at the bottom of page(above footer div).Window slide from the bottom up and make it width 100%.Also want to able scroll page when popup active.I want Popup appear from bottom.Here is my working fiddle [LINK](http://www.bootply.com/DmyamsX6qg). 
Here is my `model` css :

```
.modal-header {
padding: 2px 16px;
background-color: #2098d1;
color: white;
}
.modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}
.modal-footer {
padding: 2px 16px;
background-color: #5cb85c;
color: white;
}
.modal-header2 {
 padding: 2px 16px;
background-color: #2098d1;
color: white;
 }
.modal{
top: auto;
bottom: 10px;
outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Please make a working fiddle.  This isn't enough to go on.

Comment: Sorry, i m beginner and i don't know how to make fiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/  Make a working example, save it, post the link here.

Comment: Kindly check my updated question.thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make twitter Bootstrap popup modal slide and stick to bottom of page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26598291/make-twitter-bootstrap-popup-modal-slide-and-stick-to-bottom-of-page)

Comment: @cale_b thanks alot.yes i want this thing but can you tell me `css` according to my popup model which changes required in `css`.Here is my fiddle [LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/szu9ez95/)